# leaflet: how to create selector to link in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Need to write selector to links in leaflet popup.

I'm try something like this, but it's not work:

```
L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup("<a href='#' class='trigger-to-page'>test</a>").addTo(cities);
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a[class=trigger-to-page]').click(function() {
            console.log("123");
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x52j9da7/4/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only query elements in your popup's HTML content once the popup has opened. The content gets added to the DOM when the popup opens en removed again once it closes. How you want to solve this depends on what you're actually trying to do but there are multiple ways:

Use `L.Map`'s `popupopen` event and directly get a reference to the popup's content once it opens:

```
map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    var link = e.popup._contentNode.firstChild;
});
```

Or don't create the link from a string content but create the actual element and store a reference to that, so you can use it when you need it:

```
var link = L.DomUtil.create('a');
link.href = '#';
link.textContent = 'Test';

L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup(link).addTo(cities);
```

Comment: First is amazing solution.